# Pandas merge two data frames using logical or between common columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas data frames `A` and `B`, indexed with dates:

```
>>> A
                a      b      c
Timestamp
2018-02-19   True  False  False
2018-02-20  False   True  False
2018-02-21  False  False   True
```

and

```
>>> B
                a      b      d
Timestamp
2018-02-19  False   True   True
2018-02-20  False  False  False
2018-02-21   True   True   True
```

I want to merge these two data frames such that the merged data frame is a logical `or` between each common entry (index, column), and also including the columns that are unique to each data frame. In this case, the output would be:

```
>>> C
                a      b      c      d
Timestamp
2018-02-19   True   True  False   True
2018-02-20  False   True  False  False
2018-02-21   True   True   True   True
```

Is there a way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant and generalizable solution, but this will work for the simple example you've given.

```
A = pd.DataFrame({"a":[True, False, False],
                  'b':[False, True, False],
                  'c': [False, False, True]},
                  index=['a','b','c'])

B = pd.DataFrame({"a":[False, False, True],
                  'b':[True, False, True], 
                  'd': [True, False, True]}, 
                  index=['a','b','c'])

C = pd.concat([(A | B)[['a', 'b']], A['c'], B['d']], axis=1)

print C

       a     b      c      d
a   True  True  False   True
b  False  True  False  False
c   True  True   True   True
```

This ORs the two frames, which will produce the correct result for the columns in common (a, b), but Nan for columns c, d. So, we just slice off columns a and b, then concatenate with c and d, since they remain unchanged by the OR operation.

**EDIT:** Per your comment, here is more generalized solution, which will save you from having to know and/or hardcode the specific column names.

```
# Get all column names
all_columns = A.columns | B.columns

# Get column names in common
union = A.columns & B.columns

# Get disjoint column names
not_B = list(set(all_columns) - set(B.columns))
not_A = list(set(all_columns) - set(A.columns))

# Logical-or common columns, and concatenate disjoint columns
C = pd.concat([A[union] | B[union], A[not_B], B[not_A]], axis=1)

# If columns names get disordered because of set operations, use
# `all_columns` to reorder

print(C[all_columns])

       a     b      c      d
a   True  True  False   True
b  False  True  False  False
c   True  True   True   True
```

**EDIT 2:** Per [kmundnic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2317421/kmundnic)'s final solution, here is an updated version that works on more that two data frames.

```
# For Python 3
from functools import reduce

# A third data frame
C = pd.DataFrame({'a':[False, False, False],
                  'b':[True, True, False], 
                  'e': [True, True, True]}, 
                  index=['a','b','c'])

def logical_merge(A, B):

    # Get all column names
    all_columns = A.columns | B.columns

    # Get column names in common
    common = A.columns & B.columns

    # Get disjoint column names
    _A = [x for x in B.columns if not x in common]
    _B = [x for x in A.columns if not x in common]

    # Logical-or common columns, and concatenate disjoint columns
    return pd.concat([(A | B)[common], A[_B], B[_A]], axis=1)[all_columns]

frames = [A, B, C]

print(reduce(logical_merge, frames))

       a     b      c      d     e
a   True  True  False   True  True
b  False  True  False  False  True
c   True  True   True   True  True
```

Comment: This definitely helps, thanks! I'm still wondering if there's a more general solution to deal with the non-overlapping columns, given that tracking these is doable, but messy.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I don't think there's a really slick solution for this.  Merging or joining frames doesn't really allow you any arithmetic or logical operations on the data themselves.  Again, I could be wrong. In any case, I've added a more generalized form of my solution.  Hope it helps!

Comment: The edited solution works well. What I ended up doing to generalize to more than 2 data frames was to put your code (after the edit) into a function and then use reduce on a list of data frames. Works great :-) This was not part of the original question though, just to keep it simple.

Comment: Very slick! I've added your solution for others who may come looking.